# Rails file upload with dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, dragonfly-gem

Hello i have this problem with file upload in rails. I have set dragonfly up and it is working  nicely in admin side, however then i try to upload my file (pdf or doc) it passes empty parameter for my file attribute

okey here is the form:

```
= form_for @vacancy_application, url: {action: "create"}, html: {multipart: true, class: "block valid"} do |f|
    %fieldset
      %label{for: "vacancy_application_cv_uid"}= t("vacancy.form.cv")
      = f.file_field :cv
      = f.hidden_field :retained_cv
    %fieldset
      %label{for: "vacancy_application_mv_uid"}= t("vacancy.form.mv")
      = f.file_field :mv
      = f.hidden_field :retained_mv
    %footer
      %a.submit#submit_button{href: "#"}= t("vacancy.form.button_continue")
```

This my controller:

```
def create
    @vacancy_application = VacancyApplication.new(app_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vacancy_application.save
        format.html { redirect_to "/" }
        format.json { render json: {link: "/"}, status: :created, location: nil }
      else
        format.html { render action: "vacancy_application" }
        format.json { render json: @vacancy_application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end
```

in the model i have:

```
class VacancyApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vacancy

  dragonfly_accessor :cv
  dragonfly_accessor :mv

  validates :cv, presence: true

  alias_attribute :to_text, :title

end
```

But when i try to send form i get parameters something like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XliKgSIONsDQ4rea1OSk+EuoZHUXWOWUjYsy71vs/Rs=", "vacancy_application"=>{"retained_cv"=>"", "retained_mv"=>""}, "node_id"=>"35", "locale"=>"lv"}
```

I am missing both file upload params. I can't understand what i am doing wrong.

Is it dragonfly? does dragonfly even supports doc or pdf file uploads? Help me please :)

P.S. i am on 4.0.4 Rails version and newest dragonfly version

Comment: Please check this link, this might be helpful.     http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/rails/

Comment: I have been going trough that page again and again. Everything is set, permite params, cv_uid and mv_uid ar database, dragonfly acceessor i dont know why the form on send sends empty params!

Answer (score 0):

Okey soooooo stupid from my part. I was doing this some few weeks earlier and stopped, and now started working on this again. And i totally forgot that i was sending this form trough ajax, which of course mean that files is not sent by default because ajax does not support file transfer by default. So i refactored the form to normal form which is sent via POST and it works just fine now.....Thx on lettings me sit on my thoughts and go trough my code...good practise :)